# Is the keyword "virtual" passed on to intermediate base-classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

If I derive B from A and C from B like so:

```
A
|
B
|
C
```

Most likely I will have one or more virtual functions in A. Now, accidently I forgot to put the keyword `virtual` in B's function declaration. But to my surprise it works as if virtual was set also in B. This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class A 
{
public:
    virtual void foo(){cout << "A\n";};
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void foo(){cout << "B\n";} // a "virtual doesn't change the behaviour...
};

class C : public B
{
public:
    void foo(){cout << "C\n";}
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    c.foo();

    A *pa = new C;
    pa->foo();

    B *pb = new C;
    pb->foo();

    return 0;
}
```

If you omit also the `virtual` in `A`, the output is

```
C
A
B
```

Otherwise it is

```
C
C
C
```

even without the `virtual` in `B`!

So: Is the keyword pinherited in some way? Or do I understand something wrong here?

Comment: Surely you have a reference book?

Comment: Maybe it's just too early, but I didn't find the answer...

Answer (score 4):

If a method is `virtual` in a base class, then it is `virtual` in its subclasses, without them having to declare it as such.

Answer (score 4):

If a member is declared `virtual` in a class, it is `virtual` in its derived classes. Marking the methods `virtual` in the derived classes is not necessary, but might serve for documentation purposes. In C++11, the use of `override` would make this redundant.

Answer (score 3):

A function is virtual since its topmost base declares it as virtual and derived member function is virtual not matter it's re-declared implicitly or not.

§ 10.3.2 Virtual functions

> If a virtual member function vf is declared in a class Base and in a class Derived, derived directly or indirectly from Base, a member function vf with the same name, parameter-type-list (8.3.5), cv-qualification, and refqualifier (or absence of same) as Base::vf is declared, **then Derived::vf is also virtual (whether or not it is so declared).**

Answer (score 1):

If the method signature in a derived class is identical to the signature in a base class then the keyword virtual will be inherited automatically.